# Clarification requested for decorators

Tags: python-3.x

Got big doubts on decorators.
Below a simple test code, read in some book for beginner.

```
# -*-coding:Latin-1 -*

import sys

# The decorator.
def my_decorator(modified_function):
    """My first decorator."""

    # Modifying modified_function.
    def modifying_function():
        print("--> before")
        ret = modified_function()
        print("<-- after={}".format(ret))
        return ret

    print("Decorator is called with modified_function '{0}'".format(modified_function))

    # Return the modifying function.
    return modifying_function

@my_decorator
def hello_world():
    """Decorated function."""
    print("!! That's all folks !!")
    return (14)

print("Python version = {}".format(sys.version))

# We try to call hello_world(), but the decorator is called.
hello_world()
print("--------------------------------------------------------------")

my_decorator(hello_world)
print("--------------------------------------------------------------")

# Found this other way on the WEB, but does not work for me
my_hello  = my_decorator(hello_world)
my_hello()
print("--------------------------------------------------------------")
```

For this code, the output is rather strange, to me.
Maybe it's stupid, but ...

```
Decorator is called with modified_function '<function hello_world at 0x0000011D5FDCDEA0>'
Python version = 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:57:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
--> before
!! That's all folks !!
<-- after=14
--------------------------------------------------------------
Decorator is called with modified_function '<function my_decorator.<locals>.modifying_function at 0x0000011D5FDCDF28>'
--------------------------------------------------------------
Decorator is called with modified_function '<function my_decorator.<locals>.modifying_function at 0x0000011D5FDCDF28>'
--> before
--> before
!! That's all folks !!
<-- after=14
<-- after=14
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

1. the python version is printed after the decorator trace.
2. in 2nd and 3rd call, print("Decorator is called with modified_function ...") gives me some strange value for the function. At least, not what I expected.
3. the traces ("--> ...") and ("<-- ...") are doubled.

Any clarification for a newbie is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion has to do with the fact that you're using the decorator manually, but you *also* used Python's special syntax to apply decorators to functions as you define them: `@my_decorator`. You usually don't want to do both of those for the same function.

Try this example and it might help you understand things better:

```
# after defining my_decorator as before...

def foo():          # define a function for testing with manual decorator application
    print("foo")
print("----")
foo()               # test unmodified function
print("----")
decorated_foo = my_decorator(foo)    # manually apply the decorator (assigning to a new name)
print("----")
decorated_foo()     # test decorated function
print("----")
foo()               # confirm that the original function is still the same
print("----")
foo = my_decorator(foo) # apply the decorator again, replacing the original name this time
print("----")
foo()               # see that the original function has been replaced
print("----")
@my_decorator   # this line applies the decorator for you (like the "foo = ..." line above)
def bar(): 
    print("bar")
print("----")
bar()               # note that the decorator has already been applied to bar
print("----")
double_decorated_bar = my_decorator(bar)   # apply the decorator again, just for fun
print("----")
double_decorated_bar()   # get doubled output from the doubled decorators
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh ... OK.
Light came when I saw :

```
double_decorated_bar = my_decorator(bar)   # apply the decorator again, just for fun
```

Did not pay attention that the @decorator was not there in example.
Thx again for clarification.